# Is there a way I can avoid stopping and starting 'python manage.py runserver' on Django everytime I make a change?

Tags: python, html, css, django

Any time I make a change in the view, and HTML, or CSS, I have to stop and re-run

```
python manage.py runserver
```

for my changes to be dispayed. This is very annoying because it wastes a lot of my time trying to find the terminal and run it again. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: `runserver` should have hot reload on all files.

Comment: Yeah, but unfortunately it doesn't work on my server. If I change font size, it doesn't work until I stop and rerun.

Answer (score 2):

`python manage.py runserver` should normally perform hot reload on your Django application, except you've updated the config in the settings.py file. Check if `DEBUG = True` in settings.py

Comment: I have DEBUG = False because I have static files and my project is in production as well. My js and css files don't work without debug = false because they are wrapped in {% static 'js/filename.js' %}

Comment: In the case of static files, `Debug=False` in production because we are normally supposed to serve the static files with a web server and not Django. Thats why the changes aren't reflecting. In development `Debug=True` should work fine. You can check the Django docs for more clarification (pay attention to how static is added to `urlpatterns` too) https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/

Answer (score 0):

My advice is to use Vscode for Django developing because it gives you autosave feature so you don't have to stop and rerun the server the only thing you have to do is reload the web page. I hope it might be helpful

Comment: I already use Vscode. Is there a setting I have to change for it to work because it currently doesn't.

Comment: In file there is option of auto save

Comment: The easiest way to turn on Auto Save is with the File > Auto Save toggle that turns on and off save after a delay. For more control over Auto Save , open User or Workspace settings and find the associated settings: files.